# Как запустить комманду php -f file.php на хостинге

Tags: php, openserver, chat

Используя консоль Open Server можно запустить комманду:

```
php -f file.php
```

Это используется, например, при создании чата или системы уведомлений на сайте. В этом случае file.php содержит бесконечный цикл `while (true) {}`, внутри которого отлавливаются отправленные пользователями сообщения и другие события и формируются входящие сообщения для пользователей.

А как запустить такой файл с вечным циклом на хостинге?

Comment: так и запустить

Comment: @Ипатьев, там что на хостинге есть коммандная строка?

Comment: я добавил ссылку на вопрос, в ответах на который можно плучить базовую информацию. дальше к документации своего провайдера и гуглу